# Is Caching data in browser same as using local storage or cookies?

Tags: javascript, caching, cookies, browser, local-storage

I am a bit confused between caching and using browser's local storage to store data.
Are they both same? If not, can you please tell me the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Caching is where you store some data locally instead of fetching it over the network (or recalculating it from scratch) every time you need it.

Local storage is a place in the browser that you can store data.

You can build a cache using local storage. You can use local storage for things other than caching. You can cache data in places other than local storage. So no, they aren't the same.